# Relational Database tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table Player where playerID is the primary key. Then I have a table Game where gameDate is the primary key (of type DATETIME). Each game is played by 2 players and each player can play many games. So I believe there is a many to many relationship between Player and Game. I want to store both players for each game. I thought of adding player1ID and player2ID on the Game table or to have a bridge table PlayerPlaysGame with playerID and gameDate and then try to find who played the same game so that I get the pair. Any advice as to how I should design my database would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Phil I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that a game can only ever have two players, I suggest the following design:

```
create table PLAYER
(
  playerid   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  -- add your other columns here
);

create table GAME
(
  gameid     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  gamedate   DATETIME,
  player1id  INTEGER,
  player2id  INTEGER,
  -- add your other columns here
);
```

If you required a differing number of players per game, then I would have designed it differently - with your requirements there is no need to add an extra table & increase the query complexity.

Also note that I have made `gameid` the `PRIMARY KEY`. Using a `DATETIME` as the PK is generally not a good idea - what would happen if two games were created simultaneously?

You'll also probably want to add foreign keys to/from `GAME.player1id/player2id` and `PLAYER.playerid`.

Comment: What will be the relationship between these two tables? Two players can have the same gameID and one player can play more than 1 games. Is it many-to-many? But if it is , then wouldn't I need a bridge table?

Comment: A game only ever has 2 players. You don't ever even need to join the two tables unless you need more information about a specific player. You don't need a bridge table because there are two playerid columns (player1id and player2id) in the GAME table.